# tar with relative paths

Tags: tar

I try to create an archive with tar using relative paths. I use the following command:

```
tar czf ~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz -C ~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/ ~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/my-page-order
```

But the archived files still have absolute paths. How can I use tar with relative paths?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`~` is expanded by the shell. Don't use `~` with -C:

```
tar czf ~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz \
      -C ~ \
       webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/my-page-order
```

(tar will include `webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/my-page-order` path)
or

```
tar czf ~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz \
      -C ~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins \
       my-page-order
```

(tar will include `my-page-order` path)

Or just `cd` first....

```
cd ~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins
tar czf ~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz my-page-order
```

Comment: Explanation is wrong. It doesn't matter here that *~* is expanded by shell. What matters is that `-C` changes current working directory as explained in [anwer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22843/5355) by Lekensteyn.

Comment: No - look at the original question - the last argument is an absolute path.

Comment: So what? Both instances of *~* are expanded and the whole invocation is not working as expected only because the last argument in case of using `-C` should have been given as relative path but instead is given as absolute path. Using *~* here does not matter at all.

Answer (score 21):

`-C new_cwd` changes the current working directory to `new_cwd`. The following arguments are then evaluated relative to `new_cwd`.

Example:

```
tar czf ~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz \
  -C ~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/ my-page-order
```

Answer (score 4):

The non GNU solution if `tar` has no `-z` option, just to mention:

```
pushd ~/files/wp; tar cvf - my-page-order | gzip > my-page-order.tar.gz && rm -rf my-page-order; popd
```

EDIT (with `&&` and without `rm`):

```
pushd ~/files/wp && tar cvf - my-page-order | gzip > my-page-order.tar.gz && popd
```

Comment: (1) The question doesn’t say anything about `rm`; why do you include it in your answer? (2) Your answer archives the wrong directory. (3) Why have you changed ``tar -z`` to ``tar | gzip``? (4) As long as you’re going to use `&&`, you should probably use `&&` after the `pushd`, too.

Comment: (1) You've right
(2) really? Which is the good one?
(3) this is the point: the non GNU version of tar (eg. on Unix), has no `-z` 
(4) I would use probably `&&` in a script, but I think this is not necessary in a "one liner"

Comment: (2) OP wants to archive `~/webapps/zers/wp-content/plugins/my-page-order` with output to `~/files/wp/my-page-order.tar.gz`; your command archives `~/files/wp/my-page-order`. (3) Thanks for editing your answer to explain why you used `gzip`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with wildcard `*` but it gave me absolute paths as well so I tried later like this:

```
tar -czf ~/clientkeys.tgz -C /etc/openvpn/client/ .
```

This archives (compresses) all the given files without absolute paths.

It appears that with the dot (`.`) works well. Don't know why exactly.
I hope the answer helps.

Comment: welcome to U&L, I reformat your answer to fit conventions used here. Please note that all other 10 years old answer already answer question.