# Tar multiple files in a custom way?

Tags: linux, files, tar, software-distribution

I faced a problem of building a tarball for my application manually to prepare a distribution. My project structure looks as

```
project_root
     |
     |__resources
     |     |____config.conf
     |
   ....
     |__target
           |____release
                    |___bin
                         |___app.bin
```

So I need to tar 2 files as foolows:

```
project_root/resource/config.conf         -->   ./app/config/example/config.conf
project_root/target/release/bin/app.bin   -->   ./app/app.bin
```

There is a good example of how to [tar multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85517/is-there-a-way-to-tar-multiple-files-in-a-directory-linux-unix) and for tar with [relative paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22842/tar-with-relative-paths), but for a single file.

Is there a way to tar the two files in the scheme above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `tar` you can include the two files manually and modify the paths using the `--transform` option:

```
tar --transform=s,project_root/resources/,./app/config/example/, \
    --transform=s,project_root/target/release/bin/,./app/, \
    -cf my.tar \
    project_root/resources/config.conf \
    project_root/target/release/bin/app.bin
```

Output:

```
$ tar tf my.tar
./app/config/example/config.conf
./app/app.bin
```